# Can this block of code of mine can be improved

Tags: laravel, join, foreign-keys, relationship

[This is to populate data from two tables that one has two foreign keys from the same column as reference on the other table]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8fiv.png

[This is my schema for the table with the foreign key]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYDL0.png

This is written in laravel and it is working however i have an itchy feeling that this is wrong

Comment: Well, first of all you should include the code within the question body. Use triple backticks to start (and end) a code block. Secondly the only thing that seems wrong here is that you're using a join rather than an eloquent relationship and your `family_compositions` table looks like a pivot table rather than an entity by itself. Read more [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) on how to define a many to many relationship with additional columns in the intermediate (pivot) table

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else has commented, you should put the code in your question. More context might also be necessary as it's not clear what you are trying to return from your view(). Are you returning $citizen, $family, or both? It would also be helpful to include what version of Laravel you are using. I'll assume you are using the latest Laravel 8.

Your code should work but you are making more work for yourself if you don't utilize Laravel's relationships. If you do, all the query stuff you have in your code can be reduced to just a few short lines of code such as this:

```
public function view(Citizen $citizen)
{
    $citizen->load('family');
    return $citizen;
}
```

## Database Migration

You can shorten your migration by using foreignId(). See docs for details

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

**Before:**

```
$table->integer('client_id')->unsigned(); 
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('citizens');
```

**After:**

```
$table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained();
```

## Route Model Binding

I'm assuming your view() method is in your controller and is called from a route. Since the one parameter required is the client's id, you can use Route Model Binding and skip fetching the client from the database.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

```
public function view(Citizen $citizen)
{
    // your code
}
```

## Relationships

You seem to have relationships set up but you aren't using them to load data. You should be able to load the related objects without any manual queries.

If you have a belongsTo(One to Many) relationship on the Citizen model to the Family model, you can load it like this:

```
$citizen->load('family');
```

or just use it like this

```
$relationship = $citizen->family->relationship;
```

I don't know what the relationships between your models are but you should read up on the different relationship types in the docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships